# Add element of 2nd set in 1st set [(1, 2), (3, 4)]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, append

[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
how can I add element of 2nd tuple of list into 1st tuple ?
I want the final output as : [(1,2,3,4)]

Comment: Just a small note: those are *tuples*, not *sets*.

Answer (score 1):

Just try `itertools`

```
import itertools
out = [tuple(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ls))]
```

or else, If you want the lambda function please try below:

```
flatten = lambda l: [tuple([item for sublist in l for item in sublist])]
flatten(ls)
```

Basically, you cannot edit or add the elements, but you can create a tuple by iterating the values inside tuples.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case, that's the simple solution:

```
l = [(1, 2), (3, 4)] 
res = [l[0] + l[1]]
```

result:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

first iteration for and inner for for elements.

```
x = [(1, 2), (3, 4)] 
y=[]
for i in x:
    for e in i:
        y.append(e)
print(y)
```